# SCNAnimationPlayer From An Imported animation does not control animation with speed and stop() etc

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit

The following function loads and start an object animation.
The problem is player does not change animation speed or it can not stop it.

**dump** result is like this;

**- "player Optional(<SCNAnimationPlayer(0x280a0b580) animation=<SCNAnimation: 0x282d8e6d0, keyPath=(null) duration=2.500000 repeatCount=inf>>)"**

```
func addManAnimation(){
    
    let manScene = SCNScene(named: "man.scn")!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Armature",recursively: true)!
 
    nodeMan = SCNNode(geometry:manScene.childNode(withName: "man",
                                                  recursively: true)!.geometry)
    
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(manScene)
  
    let player = SCNScene(named: "man.scn")!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Bone", recursively: true)!.animationPlayer(forKey: "action_container-Armature")

    player?.speed = 10       
 
    dump("player \(player)")
}
```

Comment: the code seems to instantiate two different scenes. The player is thus retrieved from a scene graph that's not the one presented on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is OK, I just changed player definition.

```
let player = manScene.childNode(withName: "Bone",recursively: true)!.animationPlayer(forKey: "action_container-Armature")
```